# fancybox can't move to next/prev picture after deployment

Tags: jquery, deployment, fancybox

I have quite interesting issue with fancybox. Everything is working fine locally. After deployment to SaaS e-commerce solution:

1. Pictures are showing after click of thumb - OK
2. Showed picture can't be clicked (cursor is not changed for link) - ISSUE

Basically there is no possibility to move between pictures. Preview needs to be closed and opened for another photo.

I have tried many things, including disabling css and js scripts included on the page. Unfortunately with no luck.

Gallery is implemented at the beginning of content (slider with thumbs).
Nothing fancy with the code (standalone is working perfectly).

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<link href="css/gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>    
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script src="js/gallery.js"></script>

<div class="dg-container">
<div class="dg-items">
    <div>
    <a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="7_b.jpg"><img src="7_b.jpg" alt=""  /></a>
    <a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="6_b.jpg"><img src="6_b.jpg" alt=""  /></a>
    <a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="5_b.jpg"><img src="5_b.jpg" alt=""  /></a>
</div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've used thumbs variation, but the same issue occurred with simple approach.

Please let me know what I should check more. Where to look for implementation of links on preview photos in fancybox code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, when I worked with fancybox, I added `rel="gallery1"` in all of the `a` tags to make Prev/Next work. So all of the images were grouped under a single album/gallery.

Comment: Thanks. I've added that attribute, still not working... What is important, the code is working fine locally. The issue is on bigger site, where more scripts / css are included (many by e-commerce solution core mechanizm).

Comment: There is a ; missing in produkty-reklamowe-nfc-custom, check your console and try to remove it. It might be causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for page verification. It was SaaS script. Not sure for what reason... It's removed. Fancybox preview is still showing the photo without  possibility to click on it :(

Comment: I've also added jquery-2.0.2.min.map (it was missing). Still no luck with resolving this issue. My idea is that external css is messing with css form fancybox. I'm not familiar with fancybox css classes which are used with image preview. Maybe the only way is to review those fancybox files...

Comment: Can I see your js script which you used to initialize your fancybox?

Comment: Ofc :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8aemjyv231lxz5/gallery.js?dl=0 First line  was used for simple approach tests.

Comment: I went through your js file which seems to be ok. I also double check the fancybox, there doesn't seem to be anything special for navigation. Not sure what could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I switched to colorbox nad it's working just fine.